# Series of infinitely inscribed circles

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Start with a circle of radius 1. Split it in half along the horizontal diameter and color in the bottom half. Then inscribe a new circle inside the top half of the original circle and color in its bottom half. Repeat this process infinitely many times. (See the image below for the first few iterations.) At the end of this process, what is the total area that has been colored in?

Is there a way for this question to be easily approached?

I took the area of the first three semicircles but couldn't find a pattern.

Comment: Please include what you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: I took the area of the first iteration (pi/2) and then took the area of the second iteration (pi/8) and so on for the first three iterations, but could not find the pattern to do so.

Comment: "See the image below" ... Where ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $r_n$ represent the radius of the $n$th largest circle, with $r_0=1$. Then we have that $r_n=2r_{n+1}$, and the areas of the semicircle are $\frac{\pi}2r_n^2=2\pi r_{n+1}^2$. Or, we could say that the areas of the semicircle satisfy $A_n=4A_{n-1}$ where $A_0=\frac{\pi}2$. So we need to calculate the geometric series $$\frac{\pi}2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{4^k}$$to get the answer. I will let you complete the rest.

Comment: You should not answer very low-quality questions.

Comment: @cpiegore I will answer low-quality questions from a new user. If the user who made the question has a few posts and makes low-quality posts, then definitely I will ignore them. That is not the case for this user.

Comment: @KamalSaleh The motivation behind not answer low-quality, low-effort, and/or duplicate questions is to discourage people from asking those kinds of questions in the first place.  Answering such questions---*particularly* when they come from new users---only encourages more such questions.  And it really isn't fair to a new user to be told that several of their questions are acceptable when they are new, only for the standards to change once they have enough reputation to "know better".  Please, do not answer questions that don't meet the standards of the site.